# Referencia nula al consumir Json de manera Local con Retrofit en Android

Tags: android, json, retrofit, nullpointerexception

Estoy consumiendo un Json en LocalHost pero al querer recibir la respuesta del Json me da una referencia nula.

Este es mi Adapter:

```
public class AdapterAnmes extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

private Context context;
private List<Anime> adapterList;

public AdapterAnmes(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    this.adapterList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class animeA extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

    private ImageButton imgBotton;
    private TextView nombreEs;
    private TextView nombreJp;

    public animeA(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        imgBotton = (ImageButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.imgBAnime);
        nombreEs = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameEs);
        nombreJp = (TextView)itemView.findViewById(R.id.nameJp);
    }
}

@NonNull
@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int i) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.view_animes,viewGroup,false);
    return new animeA(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int i) {

    animeA a = (animeA)viewHolder;
    listaAnimes(a,i);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return adapterList.size();
}

public void addAnimes(List<Anime> lista){

        adapterList.addAll(lista);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

}

public void listaAnimes(animeA animes, int p){

    Glide.with(context).load(adapterList.get(p).getImgB()).into(animes.imgBotton);
    animes.nombreEs.setText(adapterList.get(p).getNameEs());
    animes.nombreJp.setText(adapterList.get(p).getNameJp());

}
```

Este es mi Fragment:

```
public class Fragment_Inicio extends Fragment {

AdapterAnmes adapterAnmes;
RecyclerView recyclerView;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment__inicio, container, false);

    adapterAnmes = new AdapterAnmes(getContext());

    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerInicio);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapterAnmes);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getContext(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));

    call();

    return view;
}

public void call(){

    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("http://[IP]:3000/api/animes/")
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    Service service = retrofit.create(Service.class);

    Call<AnimeList> call = service.getAnimes();

    call.enqueue(new Callback<AnimeList>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<AnimeList> call, Response<AnimeList> response) {

            List<Anime> aL = new ArrayList<>();
            aL.addAll(response.body().getAnimes());

            List<Anime> animesLista = new ArrayList<>();

            for(int c=0; c<aL.size();c++){
                animesLista.add(aL.get(c));
            }
                adapterAnmes.addAnimes(animesLista);
                adapterAnmes.notifyDataSetChanged();

            Log.v("Status",""+response.body());
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<AnimeList> call, Throwable t) {

        }
    });
}
```

Este es mi modelo:

```
public class Anime {

@SerializedName("nameEs")
@Expose
private String nameEs;

@SerializedName("nameJp")
@Expose
private String nameJp;


@SerializedName("sinopsis")
@Expose
private String sinopsis;

@SerializedName("fechInicio")
@Expose
private String fechInicio;

@SerializedName("fechFinal")
@Expose
private String fechFinal;

@SerializedName("genero")
@Expose
private String genero;

@SerializedName("status")
@Expose
private String status;


@SerializedName("trailer")
@Expose
private String trailer;

@SerializedName("imgB")
@Expose
private String imgB;

@SerializedName("imgS")
@Expose
private String imgS;

@SerializedName("numEP")
@Expose
private int numEP;

@SerializedName("categoria")
@Expose
private String categoria;

@SerializedName("presecuela")
@Expose
private String presecuela;

@SerializedName("secuela")
@Expose
private String secuela;

public String getNameEs() {
    return nameEs;
}

public void setNameEs(String nameEs) {
    this.nameEs = nameEs;
}

public String getNameJp() {
    return nameJp;
}

public void setNameJp(String nameJp) {
    this.nameJp = nameJp;
}

public String getSinopsis() {
    return sinopsis;
}

public void setSinopsis(String sinopsis) {
    this.sinopsis = sinopsis;
}

public String getFechInicio() {
    return fechInicio;
}

public void setFechInicio(String fechInicio) {
    this.fechInicio = fechInicio;
}

public String getFechFinal() {
    return fechFinal;
}

public void setFechFinal(String fechFinal) {
    this.fechFinal = fechFinal;
}

public String getGenero() {
    return genero;
}

public void setGenero(String genero) {
    this.genero = genero;
}

public String getStatus() {
    return status;
}

public void setStatus(String status) {
    this.status = status;
}

public String getTrailer() {
    return trailer;
}

public void setTrailer(String trailer) {
    this.trailer = trailer;
}

public String getImgB() {
    return imgB;
}

public void setImgB(String imgB) {
    this.imgB = imgB;
}

public String getImgS() {
    return imgS;
}

public void setImgS(String imgS) {
    this.imgS = imgS;
}

public int getNumEP() {
    return numEP;
}

public void setNumEP(int numEP) {
    this.numEP = numEP;
}

public String getCategoria() {
    return categoria;
}

public void setCategoria(String categoria) {
    this.categoria = categoria;
}

public String getPresecuela() {
    return presecuela;
}

public void setPresecuela(String presecuela) {
    this.presecuela = presecuela;
}

public String getSecuela() {
    return secuela;
}

public void setSecuela(String secuela) {
    this.secuela = secuela;
}
```

}

Esta es mi List:

```
public class AnimeList {

@SerializedName("animes")
private List<Anime> animes;

public List<Anime> getAnimes() {
    return animes;
}

public void setAnimes(List<Anime> animes) {
    this.animes = animes;
}

@Override
public String toString(){
    return "AnimeList{" +
            "Animes =" + animes + '}';
}
```

}

Esta es mi Interface:

```
public interface Service {

@GET("animes")
Call<AnimeList> getAnimes();
```

Este es el error que me tira:

[image: Error de Referencia Nula]

Esta es la linea donde me tira el error (Que es donde recibe el Json null)

[image: Linea donde esta el error del Json Nulo]

y esta es la Url donde subi el Json para referencias:

https://api.myjson.com/bins/keqr0

Answer (score -1):

No es una respuesta pero te ayuda a ver que puede estar pasando:

Agregale un interceptor para ver que te está llegando por el cable, por ahí no te llega el json que esperás o por ahí te vueve un error dentro de un HTTP code de success. 
Después para producción lo sacás..

```
        HttpLoggingInterceptor interceptor = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
        interceptor.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);

        OkHttpClient.Builder httpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder();

        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
                               .create();

        httpClient.addInterceptor(interceptor)
        .connectTimeout(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .readTimeout(20,TimeUnit.SECONDS)
        .writeTimeout(15, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(httpClient.build())
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
                .build();
```

En LogCat vas a ver que te loguea lo que mandas y lo que recibis con todos los headers.

Por otro lado también ponele un `Log.e()` aunque sea al `onFailure()`